# How do I correctly display a UINavigationController when tapping a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm new to iOS development. I have an app that has a `UINavigationController` (with an embedded `UITableViewController`, call it TableView1) and I need to display another `UITableView` (TableView2) on the tap of a `UITableViewCell` for TableView1.

I did some online searching and didn't really find anything super useful, but what I was able to find said that I have to present TableView2 instead of pushing it. Everything is working correctly, except that TableView2 doesn't have a back button and I have to create my own `UIBarButtonItem` and assign to `leftBarButtonItem` of the `navigationItem`.

This is all fine, except for the fact that I can't help but feel like I'm doing it wrong. Is there any easier way (or a more correct way) to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Code for TableView1

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController
                                            animated:YES
                                          completion:nil];
}
```

EDIT: Along with this question, if I find out I'm doing this the correct way, how do I get the normal back button to display? or can I?

Comment: Why don't you want to push it?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to push it. I tried to push the UINavigationController, but nothing would happen. I set up the segue to push, but nothing. Did some research and saw that you can't push a UINavigationController from a UITableViewCell. Not sure if that's correct or not, all I know is pushing didn't work, but when I changed the code to presentViewController, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present it directly from that view controller:

```
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or use `pushViewController`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this, and got the same result as I was getting before.

Comment: @dstepan I've updated my answer to include how to push a view controller

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: Please note in my answer that I push **`tableViewController`**

Comment: AH! You are a saint. Pushing just the UITableViewController worked perfectly!